# What is Jump to Next placeholder shortcut key in Xcode is supposed to do?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I have used it, but i'm not sure what it does!

And also Jump to Next PlaceHolder to do? No idea on this shortcut key too!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A placeholder is the fillable area in an auto-completed code snippet.

Say I type `[UIView ani`, XCode will autocomplete to this :

[image]

The placeholders are the three pieces of code on gray background, which you can double-click to edit.

Comment: Ok got it. I have been using Tab to do so till now and I guess there is no reason one would go for this Ctl+Alt+/ instead of a simple TAB shortcut. - BTW thanks for clearing my doubt.